# Jenkinsfile: publish test results even if test step fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

In my `Jenkinsfile` I have a stage `Test` where I run a `npm` test command step as well as a `junit` step to archive test results.

```
stage('Test') {
  steps {
    sh 'npm run test-ci'
    junit 'test-results.xml'
  }
}
```

How can I use `try`/`finally` correctly to run the `junit` step even if the `sh 'npm run test-ci'` step fails?

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-failure)? You need to *"Toggle Scripted Pipeline"* if you're using that syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the post stage, https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post.

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
      stage('Test') {
        steps {
          sh 'npm run test-ci'
        }
      }
      post { 
        always { 
          junit 'test-results.xml'   
        }
    }
}
```

Also have a look at this blog post, it explains it further, https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/10/declarative-html-publisher/